# What things needs to be taken care of while writing Development Policy for Project?

Tags: project-management, document-management

I've been assigned to create a development policy for our project which is a test case management web application using Spring MVC and Java.

For instance, I think I would have to create the coding guidelines to be followed by the new joinees in the team. Also including the project architecture so that whenever a new joinee joins the team he can go through the policies and understand the work culture in the Project. Apart from this what are other things which should be part of the Development policies? Please guide me as I'm new for this kind of tasks.

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: Too broad.  You're asking us to write what is essentially a book, or the better part of a book chapter.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I wouldn't expect all of you experts to write a book for me but atleast you could have pointed me towards right direction.. Thank you anyways for commenting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing this is a student project.
But whatever, every dev team should document agreed policies.
That does not mean one guy writes a book up front; you can guarantee the rest of the team will ignore such a thing.

What is required is a team discussion regards ways of operating,and someone to document that.
This should be within some kind of shared space such as a wiki.

Issue to consider include :

1. source control approach
2. code reviews, pull requests etc.
3. test standards
4. expectations around documentation: in code, elsewhere, none at all, design, requirements etc.
5. continual build and release or whatever
6. everyone cleans up their own mess or core maintainer?
7. Agile, scrum etc type practices to be followed.
8. Etc. Etc.

Build this incrementally,  day by day by capturing team discussion.